# Given a property on a relationship, how to return the path and node attributes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to neo4j and am trying to map the longest path to a known node. In this example there is only a single, straight path. (For example, node1 => node2 => node3 => node4 => node5 => node6). How can I write that query?

A complication is to limit only relationships and with a certain property. For example, all the relationships are types :KNOWS, but then there is an attribute on it of "signal", and I want to run the query only for relationships r:KNOWS where r.signal = 10.

Below is what works to get the last two nodes in the path:

```
MATCH (end)<-[r:knows]-(node)
WHERE r.signal = 10
AND end.name = 4
RETURN node.name, end.name, r.signal
```

Here is my next attempt using the * to get all lengths, and a combination of filter and extract to handle the collection:

```
MATCH (end)<-[r:knows*]-(node)
WHERE end.name = 4
WITH end, node, [x IN r WHERE x.signal = 10 | x.signal] as signals
RETURN node.name, end.name, signals
```

But it's still not quite right since it returns all iterations, and only the pairs. I'd like to find the longest path, and return an array of all the node names (not just a pair at a time). Any pointers on how to approach this are much appreciated, or helpful links to tutorials. I've already done the neo4j online training.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get a maximum length/longest path:

```
MATCH p=(end {name: 4})<-[r:knows*]-(node)
WITH max(length(p)) as longestPathLength
MATCH p2=(end {name: 4})<-[r:knows*]-(node)
WITH [x IN nodes(p2) | x.signal] as signals, 
     p2 as p2, 
     longestPathLength as longestPathLength
WHERE length(p2) = longestPathLength
RETURN p2, signals;
```

First, you need to be matching the path and assigning it to a variable, here `p` and `p2`.  You can extract the node names by using the collection function as you were, across `nodes(p2)`.   Finally, to find the longest path length, just find all of them, and select the path with the maximum length.  Then go back and extract only node names from paths that happen to have that length.

This probably isn't the most efficient way to do it, but it looks like it works.